# Is there a script that can create links on all cells from a list and once you click on them to send you to the respective (same named) tabs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a list with 10 items and have created 10 tabs named from those 10 items. Is there a script that can creates links on the List Name cells and once you click on them to send you to the respective (same named) tabs?